# Is $Tr( (A^{-1}B)^2 ) \leq Tr ( A^{-1}B )$ if $A \geq B \geq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Let $A$ be simmetric positive definite, $B$ simetric positive semi definite. And $A - B$ positive semi definite, i.e $A \geq B$

How can I convince myself that $$Tr( (A^{-1}B)^2 ) \leq Tr ( A^{-1}B )$$

Comment: Use that Trace is sum eigenvalues and the fact that $A$ and $B$ are positive definite

Comment: I do not understand your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same solution was on the road here.
It's an "algebraic" solution that works in a general Hilbert space $H$ (with a trace on some operator algebra on it).

Let $\bar A$ be the inverse of $A$, $\bar A=A^{-1}$.

It is **enough** to show
$$
\underbrace{\bar A^{1/2}\; B\bar A B\; \bar A^{1/2}}
_{(\bar A^{1/2}\; B\; \bar A^{1/2})^2}
\le 
\bar A^{1/2}\; B\; \bar A^{1/2}\ ,
$$
since after applying the trace we can "move" the one $\bar A^{1/2}$ from one end to the other end. 
For the above, it is further successively enough to show the following inequalities involving selfadjoint operators $\ge 0$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\bar A^{1/2}\; B\; \bar A^{1/2} &\le I \ ,\\
A^{1/2}\bar A^{1/2}\ B\; \bar A^{1/2} A^{1/2}&\le A^{1/2}\ I\ A^{1/2} \ ,\\
B&\le A\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The last inequality is given.

Comment: I don't see how you get to proove the first inequality with the last three.

Comment: We have to show $T^2\le T$ for $T=A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}$. For this i needed $T\le I$.

Comment: I was stumbling with showing that $T \leq I \implies  T^2 \leq T$. Now I realize how trivial is that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**YES**

I found the answer to my question shortly after asking. I will post it so nayone else who has the same question can use it.

If all eigenvalues of $A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}$ $\lambda_1, \ldots \lambda_n$ are are smaller than $1$. Then  $Tr(  (A^{-1}B)^2  ) = Tr(  (A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})^2) = \sum \lambda_i^2 \leq \sum \lambda_i = Tr( A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2} ) = Tr ( A^{-1}B )$.

Now notice that $A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2} \leq Id$, because $ A \geq B \implies Id \geq A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}$. This gives that $0 \leq \lambda_i \leq 1$.